# how to stuff date and time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

i am having trouble stuffing the date and time for the same item in SQL sever. Below are three simple records.

```
Date_Time                ID
9/6/2018 5:36:30 PM      12345
9/6/2018 6:19:02 PM      12345
9/7/2018 4:15:55 AM      12345
```

I would like my result to be in 1 row and the Date_Time column got stuffed followed by a comma (,).

```
Date_Time                                                       ID
9/6/2018 5:36:30 PM, 9/6/2018 6:19:02 PM, 9/7/2018 4:15:55 AM   12345
```

Would someone please point me to the right direction/link or a simple query to resolve the issue?

Thanks,
XH.

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: It's SQL Sever 07.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sql server 2017 or above you can use string_agg as below:

```
select id, string_agg(convert(varchar,DATE_Time, 22), ', ')
    from #YourTable 
    group by id
```

If it is below sql server 2017 you can use below query:

```
select id, stuff ((
    select ', ' + convert(nvarchar, date_time, 22) from #Table2 where id = t.id
    for xml path('')
    ),1,2,'') as dates
from #Table2 t
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks, Kannan. this is the result: Sep  6 2018  5:36PM, Sep  6 2018  6:19PM, Sep  7 2018  4:15AM. How do I change the format to show as such: 9/6/2018 5:36:30 PM, 9/6/2018 6:19:02 PM, 9/7/2018 4:15:55 AM? much appreciated.

Comment: use 22 in convert

Answer (score -1):

On MySQL

`SELECT id, group_concat(Date_Time) as test FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY ID`